# Using div to make page center

Tags: html

Say logo1 and logo2 is 100px long each and I want to cover half of the logo up.
Whats the best way and neatest way of making two logos over lap and making them in the center of page.

Answer (score 1):

Put both your logos in a `<div>` and give it `margin: 0 auto;`.

Then give `logo2` `z-index: 1;` so that it is layered on top of `logo1`.

[Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhx5r/39/).

Page:

```
<div class="center">
    <img src="Link/To/Your/Image/For/Logo1" id="logo1" />
    <img src="Link/To/Your/Image/For/Logo2" id="logo2" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    width: 210px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#logo2 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;    
}
```

If you make the logos overlap even more (e.g. move `logo2` to overlap by 50px with `left: -50px;` then you must also change the position of the surrounding div to match the overlap with `left: 50px;`, so the the left positioning for `#logo2` and `.center` should be the same but opposite.

Comment: what if my logo different size to ur 100x80 boxes?

Comment: The height of the image is irrelevant, and although you stated that they were both width 100px, if they have different widths then just change `width: 210px;` in the css to the combined widths of the images + 10. e.g. logo1 = 200px, logo2 = 130px, then the css should be `width: 340px;`

Comment: Here's an example with different widths and heights: http://jsfiddle.net/Jhx5r/40/

Comment: If the heights are different it will look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jhx5r/41/
And if they have different heights and you want them both at the top then just add to the one that is lower down `top: -DifferenceBetweenHeights;` like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Jhx5r/42/

Comment: @prageeth yours only works for a specific resolution, check out what happens when the browser width changes... its still 450px from the left, not in the center: http://jsfiddle.net/sFqkX/

Comment: @user1056534 plan on accepting either of the answers anytime soon?

Comment: coming back to this, center is only from bottom right corner of logo1? if i put logo2 left:-50px, then the logos are not center?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood. I have a solution and i have changed the answer to solve the issue, adding css for .center `position: relative;` and `left: 10px;`. This left value must match the overlap amount.

Comment: @user1056534 If this has solved your issue (which I assume it has as you haven't returned with further problems), then please accept an answer. If you don't accept answers for your questions it will decrease your chances of getting answers to future questions from the community.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the style `position:absolute;`. Following is an example.

```
<style>
    .container{
        border:solid 1px red;
        text-align:center;
        height:500px;
    }
    #logo1, #logo2{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:200px;
    }
    #logo1{
        border:solid 1px green;
        left:450px;
    }
    #logo2{
        border:solid 1px blue;
        left:540px;/*note 540 = 450 + (100 - 10)*/
    }

</style>
```

Page:

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="logo1"></div>
   <div id="logo2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: didnt seem to work, logo2 is underneath logo 1 and not on the same row

Comment: Sorry, but I now again checked with IE, Chrome and FF. It works for me. Both the small Divs are on the same row and overlapping 10px.